# How to make derived class of a memory-aligned class lose alignment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-alignment

Suppose one class is declared as having a specific alignment. And that I cannot modify that base class.

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED16(a) __declspec(align(16)) a

ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED16(class) btVector3
{};

class Vector3 : public btVector3
{};
```

Is it possible to make the derived class Vector3 lose that alignment ?

Under MSVC alignment is quite constraining as it prevents from passing by value. My derived class doesn't particularly need it, and in template writing it is convenient to have classes that can be passed by values.

Comment: Cant you just remove that declaration?

Comment: No, it is from an external library. I'm using their Vector3 for convenience and to not reinvent the wheel, but I don't need the specific alignment.

Comment: Not sure then, but the inner mechanics of the class might not work if the alignment is not kept

Comment: I believe they would, the alignment is related to containers and arrays of this class that the library uses. So the library needs the alignment in the base class but I don't in my derived class.

Comment: You know all code assumes proper alignment, mis-alignment causes broken synchronization, bad performance and maybe even a hardware-trap? And as you derived is a base, reducing derived's alignment does that?

Comment: But what if methods like push make use of that alignment?

Comment: This is pretty easy to do, __declspec(align) is only a *promise*.  The C++ compiler can only enforce it if it determines the address of the object itself.  It cannot do it for library functions like malloc() and ::operator new, they are missing an argument to indicate the required alignment.  A pretty nasty flaw in the standard library.  So using the placement-new operator is enough to get it mis-aligned anyway you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful - if btVector3 is coming from the Bullet Physics Library (where bt is the prefix on their math functions) the btVector3 is aligned to 16 byte boundaries because of the SIMD math functions. Furthermore, the btVector3 is defined as a union of 4 floats and a 128 bit type, which requires 16 byte alignment in most environments. See http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btVector3_8h_source.html

Trying to use the math library without the alignment requirements will cause some operations fail and your methods to act in an undefined way. Better to live with the alignment, or find a different library.